# Java null check on multiple properties with Optionals

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

What's the most efficient way on java 11 to null check multiple fields from the same object? I was going with optionals but I don't understand how to use them with more fields of the same object

```java
    Map<String, NestedQuery> nested = new HashMap<>();
    if (getSentDate() != null) {
      if (getSentDate().getFrom() != null && getSentDate().getTo() != null) {
        nested.put(...); 
      }
    }
    return nested;
```

In my case `getSentdate()` returns an object that has `getFrom()` and `getTo()` that are values that may or may not be null

I tried with this but the use of .ifPresent inside an if clause is a big no no

```java
    Map<String, NestedQuery> nested = new HashMap<>();
    Optional.ofNullable(getSentDate())
        .ifPresent(sentDate -> {
          Optional<String> from = Optional.ofNullable(sentDate.getFrom());
          Optional<String> to = Optional.ofNullable(sentDate.getTo());
          if(from.isPresent() && to.isPresent()){
            nested.put(...);
          }
        });
    return nested;
```

Comment: The general advice is to use optionals only as return values.

Comment: Your first way is efficient! Optional isn't your friend in this case. `if (getSentDate() != null && getSentDate().getFrom() != null && getSentDate().getTo() != null){...}`

Comment: Basically what @HadiJ said, but mind the existence of local variables (since 1.0) which allow you to avoid calling the same methods over and over again.

Comment: I think @HadiJ has the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been said in the comments above your original code is actually quite efficient (we probably need some criteria for effectiveness):

```
if (getSentDate() != null) {
      if (getSentDate().getFrom() != null && getSentDate().getTo() != null) {
```

However if you really want to use an `Optional` to eliminate **some** of the null checks it is enough to use just one:

```
Optional.ofNullable(getSentDate())
        .filter(sentDate -> Objects.nonNull(sentDate.getFrom()))
        .filter(sentDate -> Objects.nonNull(sentDate.getTo())) 
        .ifPresent(date -> nested.put(...));
```

in this case `.ifPresent(date -> nested.put(...))` is executed only when all 3 conditions are met: `getSentDate()` is not `null`, `sentDate.getFrom()` is not `null` and `sentDate.getTo()` is not `null` as well. However we still have a null check and we are "abusing" [Objects#nonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) method since:

> API Note:
>       This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::nonNull)

An equivalent for this is

```
Optional.ofNullable(getSentDate())
        .filter(sentDate -> sentDate.getFrom() != null)
        .filter(sentDate -> sentDate.getTo() != null) 
        .ifPresent(date -> nested.put(...));
```

Please note as well that this actually "violates" [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) usage

> API Note:
>       Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null is likely to cause errors.

Comment: So there isn't a right way to populate a map conditionally like this without doing all the null checks explicitly?

Comment: @venturieffect, there is but is not really optimal/elegant, you can wrap every filed into an Optional to avoid null check `Optional.ofNullable(getSentDate())
                    .filter(sentDate -> Optinal.ofNullable(sentDate.getFrom()).isPresent())
                    .filter(sentDate -> Optinal.ofNullable(sentDate.getTo()).isPresent())
                    .ifPresent(date -> nested.put(...));`, but it doesn;t really give you any advantage

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, here a NestedQuery has an optional send date, and a SendDate has optional getFrom and getTo values. You can use ifpresent ans ispresent to check if the value is present

```
private interface SendDate {

Optional<Object> getFrom();

Optional<Object> getTo();
}

private interface NestedQuery {

public Optional<SendDate> getSendDate();
}

private static NestedQuery createNestedQuery() {
return Optional::empty;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
final Map<String, NestedQuery> nested = new HashMap<>();
final NestedQuery nestedQuery = createNestedQuery();
nestedQuery.getSendDate().ifPresent(sendDate -> {
    if (sendDate.getFrom().isPresent() && sendDate.getTo().isPresent())
    nested.put("", nestedQuery);
});
System.out.println(nested.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you cant change the interface / class NestedQuery and SendDate to use optionals then doing actual null checks is probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Though the conditional expression using && and its short-circuiting behavior is the best you can get while dealing with multiple levels of attributes. Still, for a *single level of nesting*, you can easily introduce a utility which conforms none of the attributes inside are null.

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> boolean noneNull(T... args) {
    return Arrays.stream(args).noneMatch(Objects::isNull);
}
```

and use it as

```
if(noneNull(sentDate.getFrom(), sentDate.getTo())) {
    nested.put(...)
}
```

and notice, there is no involvement of `Optional` for this which in general is not required for a check of null objects.

Comment: The OP asked for “the most efficient way”. I’d say, creating a temporary array and performing a stream operation for checking two references for `null` is on the opposite side of the scale.

Comment: @Holger I had some thought put behind it and undoubtedly the `&&` serves better as mentioned in the answer as well, but the doubts further(happy to read through links) - Are you pointing to the stream operation specifically as costly or iterating over an array as well?  - Does the count of arguments matter here by any chance as well to move the scale in the other direction? (I was thinking about similar [`commons` implementation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#anyNotNull-java.lang.Object...-) while asking.)

Comment: Having more arguments would improve the gain in source code brevity from negligible to tiny, but the performance would actually become worse. Both, the `&&` operator and the `noneMatch` operation are short-circuiting, but the array creation for the varargs call is not. And the larger the array, the less likely are JVMs eliminating it. Since the test method is looping over it, the HotSpot JVM would never eliminate it.